# How to display data in columns in two variables with the same format?

Tags: bash, columns, echo

I coded the following to display data formatted in columns:

```
str1='hello i      am robert
and your ma frnd'

str2='thisisaverylongword thisistoohehehe andherefinishthe         string
hereis a other linefortheexample'

IFS=$'\n'
echo '----------------------'
echo 'STRING SHORT'
echo '----------------------'
echo "$str1" | column -t
echo
echo '----------------------'
echo 'STRING LONG'
echo '----------------------'
echo "$str2" | column -t
```

Which outputs:

```
----------------------
STRING SHORT
----------------------
hello  i     am  robert
and    your  ma  frnd

----------------------
STRING LONG
----------------------
thisisaverylongword  thisistoohehehe  andherefinishthe  string
hereis               a                other             linefortheexample
```

Ok, now I'm trying to format the string with the same pattern, but without merge them.

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
----------------------
STRING SHORT
----------------------
hello                i                am                robert
and                  your             ma                frnd

----------------------
STRING LONG
----------------------
thisisaverylongword  thisistoohehehe  andherefinishthe  string
hereis               a                other             linefortheexample
```

Do you have any idea to do it? May be merging the strings and splitting it before the format?

Note that this is only an example, I'm looking for a generic solution, not only for this specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to

```
printf "%s\n" "$str1" "$str2" | column -t
```

and *then* inject the headers

Generically, I'd write something like this that uses arrays:

```
strings=( "$str1" "$str2" ... )
headers=( "STRING SHORT" "STRING LONG" ... )

exec 3< <( printf "%s\n" "${strings[@]}" | column -t )
for (( i=0; i<${#strings[@]}; i++)); do
    printf -- "----\n%s\n----\n" "${headers[i]}"
    n=$(wc -l <<< "${strings[i]}")
    for (( j=1; j<=n; j++ )); do
        IFS= read -r line <&3
        echo "$line"
    done
    echo
done
exec 3<&-
```

Notes:

- `<( ... )` is a bash [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution). That is a plain pipeline that gets handled as a filename. It's very handy in situtation where you would use a pipe but can't have the right side of the pipe executed in a subshell.
- here, we are opening file descriptor # 3 to read data from this "file": `exec 3<file`
- `read -r line <&3` reads a line of data from the process substitution
- `exec 3<&-` closes the file descriptor
- read more about redirections here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections
- I could have used a `printf ... | while read line; do ...; done` but I thought the for loops would make the counting easier.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect! could you add explicative comments, please? I'm really interested in it. :)

Comment: Any specific questions? Everything in there is documented in the bash manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Comment: There is an issue: If the first string of `strings` is empty `strings=("" "$str1" "$str2" ... )`, then prints the line of the next string.